# How many instances exists when a InstanceContextMode.Single WCF service exposes multiple endpoints?

Tags: .net, wcf, servicebehavior, instancecontextmode

Does the `ServiceBehavior` setting `InstanceContextMode.Single` sets a single instance regardless of the number of endpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will get only one instance with `InstanceContextMode.Single`, regardless of the number of endpoints.

Comment: So it means if use loadbalncer(I mean hosting the wcf stuff on more than 1 server and having multiple endpoints), using Singelton mode is not a correct one!?. Adding ConcurrencyMode =  ConcurrencyMode.Multiple to sinlgelton also might not help as there is just one instance of the service!